# static and set_global together: how come?

Tags: c

I see the following code:

```
static __SECTION("set_global")  struct something * p = NULL;
```

I am confused. "static" means local scope, to this C file. Above the line there is comment about set_global: ELF section for global variables.

So this basically makes variable p a global variable and can be accessed by any source code?

Answer (score 1):

Static does not identify local scope, it means mean translation unit (the source file) only scope.

The `static` keyword identifies a variable that is to be allocated globally and whose lifetime is the entire program run.

The __SECTION("name") puts the variable in the "name" section, but does not influence the visibility of the variable.

I believe that this:

```
static __SECTION("set_global")  struct something * p = NULL;
```

declares p as a pointer to a somthing structure that will have a lifetime equal to the run of the program, which is stored in a section named "set_global", and which is (at most, based on the location of the declaration) visible throughout the file in which it is declared.